# iPhone: How to know music item is unsynced?

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm creating a music app.

Are there a way to know if MPMediaItem is unsynced while my app is playing it or displaying it on a table view?

On a table view, now I check if MPMediaItem is nil or not.
Is it good way?

A playing MPMediaItem doesn't become nil after it is unsynced.
So I can't know it is unsynced or not.

I thought there was a notification of syncing iTunes.
But I can't find such notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(notification_iPodLibraryDidChange:)
                                             name: MPMediaLibraryDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[MPMediaLibrary defaultMediaLibrary] beginGeneratingLibraryChangeNotifications];
```

Not sure what happens if your library changes under you but I suppose it would be easy enough to check using the above notification.

Comment: thanks! That is the notification i was looking for. Document of the notification says: `When MPMediaLibraryDidChangeNotification is posted, your application should reevaluate items or playlists that you previously cached.`. I think this means that i should search items from ipod library again after getting notification. You and the document probably solved my problem. thanks.